# How can I import a bundled Mercurial repository on BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket

BitBucket's import page:
https://bitbucket.org/repo/import
(you might need to be logged in)
does not seem to allow you to upload a file; specifically, not the result of  mercurial's `hg bundle' command.

How can you import such a bundle file?